# Is it possible to pass a class as a parameter to a function in c++?

Tags: c++

I have a function with void * as one of its parameters (the void is used as a generic object). But to be able to call a function in that generic object, I need to cast it first, and for that I need to know what type the class is. And I wanted to know, is it possible to pass a class or some information that allows me to cast the object as a function parameter?

Comment: are you the owner of the function getting void* as a parameter or it is part of an external api?

Comment: It is usually a very bad idea provide a function with void* as an input. There are better way to achieve generic behavior: using template or inheritance. You should rethink your design.

Comment: If i don't find a way I'll do

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By any chance have you looked into [Templates](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/)?

An example would be something such as

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    template<typename CastClass>
    void DoSomething(void* someArg)
    {
         (CastClass)someArg;
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
class A{ }; // Some random test class

SomeClass test;
A a;
test.DoSomething<int>(&a); // The template parameter can be anything. 
                           // I just have int to make it a smaller example.
```

Comment: But I need that function to be inside a class, and I can't make that class a template

Comment: Thank you. And how would it be used?

Comment: one question, could I (in the definition of the class) call any method of someArg in DoSomething?

Comment: I may be a little confused by this question, but do you mean can you do something such as ((CastClass)someArg)->SomeFunc()? If so, then yes (if the function exists).